# Swift kitura multi language support

Tags: swift, internationalization, mustache, kitura

Is there any multi language support for the Swift kitura framework? I would like to use the mustache template engine which is available as kitura component.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "built-in" multi-language support in Kitura. Having said that one could simply do the classic solution, which is to always keep the actual message text in external files (presumably JSON key/value dictionaries). The appropriate file for the laguage in question is read in and passed in to the Mustache template in the context. In the template all text to be displayed in a substitution made from a key from read in messages file.